# OpenLayers library renders MapServer WMS layer with errors

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapserver

I have set up MapServer WMS service with a point layer. And now I'm trying to write a simple WMS client using OpenLayers library. Generally, I have got some results, but with some issues. Some points are smaller than others. I have tried to connect to my WMS service using QGIS and Leaflet library. Results are perfect! There are some troubles with OpenLayers lib. What's wrong with this example?

Client side:

- Openlayers v4.0.1
- Windows 7 x64 SP1
- Chrome 57.0.2987.133 [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36]
- IE 11.0.9600 [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko]
- Firefox 51.0.1 [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0]

Server side:

- ms4w 3.1.4

Live example: http://vector-sol.ru/apps/ol.html
Download zip with shape file, html page and config map file: http://map31.ru:8888/example.zip

html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
    html, body { 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
        height:100%; 
    }
    #info { 
        position:absolute; 
        z-index:10; 
        background-color:yellow; 
        right: 0;
    }
    #map { 
        height:100%; 
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map">
        <div id="info">OpenLayers example</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
                  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                  url: 'http://map31.ru:8888/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=../htdocs/mydemo/wms_ol.map',
                  params: { 'LAYERS': 'pop_places', 'TILED': true },
                  serverType: 'mapserver'
              }))
          })          
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

MAP file:

```
MAP

  NAME "WMS"
  IMAGETYPE      PNG
  EXTENT -180 -90 180 90 # Geographic
  SIZE 800 400
  IMAGECOLOR 220 221 239  

  SYMBOL
    NAME 'circle'
    TYPE ELLIPSE
    POINTS 1 1 END
    FILLED TRUE
  END 

  WEB
    METADATA
        wms_title                  "WMS Demo"
        wms_abstract               "Demo WMS Server"
        wms_onlineresource         "http://map31.ru:8888/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=../htdocs/mydemo/wms_ol.map&"
        wms_srs                    "EPSG:4326"
        wms_getfeatureinfo         "http://map31.ru:8888/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=../htdocs/mydemo/wms_ol.map&"
        wms_featureinfoformat      "text/plain"
        wms_enable_request          "*"
    END
  END  

  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END

    LAYER
      NAME "pop_places"
      TYPE POINT
      STATUS ON
      DATA 'shape/ne_10m_populated_places.shp'
      PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
      END
      CLASS
        NAME "Pop Places"
        STYLE
          COLOR 10 100 50
          SYMBOL 'circle'
          SIZE 6        
        END
      END

      METADATA
        wms_title "Populated Places"
        wms_abstract "Populated places of the world"
        wms_srs "EPSG:4326"
        wms_include_items "all"
        wms_enable_request "*"
        #wms_extent "-180 -90 180 90"
      END     

    END # layer  

END
```

Answer (score 0):

The `projection: 'EPSG:4326'` setting triggers client-side raster reprojection, because the default view projection is `'EPSG:3857'`. You probably want to make your map work in that projection, and simply remove the `projection: 'EPSG:4326'` line from your `ol.source.TileWMS` configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I had to changed my WMS server output projection to 'EPSG:3857'. And after this step removing the projection: 'EPSG:4326' line    had an affect. So, this is server side solution. But what's wrong with OpenLayers reprojection?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. But the target resolution changes with the latitude when reprojecting between EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3857. Otherwise you'd get blurred images.

Comment: or you could change `wms_srs "EPSG:4326"` to `wms_srs "EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857"` to get server side reprojection